# How to get the same query with Mongoose as mongodb db.<collection>.find()?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So db.cats.find() in the mongodb console gives this result:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5b71651978e7d706d3e0a507"),
    "name": "George",
    "age": 11,
    "temperament": "Grouchy",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5b7186b86bbf270d4a5daa01"),
    "name": "Soros",
    "age": 89,
    "temperament": "Evil",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5b7194ffef27d50d9eb7464d"),
    "name": "Sminem",
    "age": 15,
    "temperament": "cool",
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

while mongoose

```
 Cat.find({}, function(err, cats){
if(err){
    console.log("Error");
    console.log(err);
} else {
    console.log(cats);
}
});
```

gives the same, but with [] brackets

```
[
  {
    _id: "5b71651978e7d706d3e0a507",
    name: "George",
    age: 11,
    temperament: "Grouchy",
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: "5b7186b86bbf270d4a5daa01",
    name: "Soros",
    age: 89,
    temperament: "Evil",
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: "5b7194ffef27d50d9eb7464d",
    name: "Sminem",
    age: 15,
    temperament: "cool",
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

So how do I get the same, but with no square brackets[]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use :

```
Cat.findOne({}, function(err, cats){
  if(err){
    console.log("Error");
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log(cats);
 }
});
```

find return an array of docs and findOne return one doc object.

Comment: But how would I get all the cats without getting the [] brackets?

Comment: do you want to find one doc or multiple? if you want to have multiple then you have to use find and the result will be an array with brackets. if you want to find one doc then use findOne and it will return a single doc object.

Comment: I wanted to have an api like this: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1 ,but now I realised it was a single document. Thanks for clearing the confusion.